# How to deal with mutliple pipes in shell program?

Tags: python, pipe, fork, python-os

I am making a shell in python using the os library, and I want to make multiple pipes functionality, but I am getting stuck because I an unsure how to deal with STDOUT and children and parents.

I am imagining that I have to keep on writing the result to stdout and duplicate it in case of more pipes.

So if I have this command, I should get only the line where var is found:

```sh
ls -l / | grep v | grep var
```

Then i made the shell divide the commands into a list of lists of strings:

```py
command = [['ls', '-l', '/'], ['grep', 'root'], ['grep', 'var']]
```

Then I need to fork and duplicate the output of the first two in a new child, and pass the output into the last.

I am really confused about how I can do this with more than 1 pipe, and even more confused about how I can do it dynamically.

I am sitting right now and trying different ways of just adding a second pipe statically to the program, but I have some ideas about how it should be possible, to dynamically add *n* pipes to the program by using iteration or recursion.

My working code to do one pipe is like this:

```py
from os import (
    execvp,
    wait,
    fork,
    pipe,
    dup2,
    _exit,
    close,
)

STDIN   = 0
STDOUT  = 1
CHILD   = 0


def command(cmd):
    try:
        execvp(cmd[0].strip(), cmd)
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)

def piping(cmd):
    reading, writing = pipe()
    pid = fork()
    if pid > CHILD:
        wait()
        close(writing)
        dup2(reading, STDIN)
        command(cmd[1])
    elif pid == CHILD:
        close(reading)
        dup2(writing, STDOUT)
        command(cmd[0])
        _exit(0)

def main():
    pid = fork()
    if pid > CHILD:
        wait()
    if pid == CHILD:
        piping([['ls','-al','/'],['grep','v'],['grep','var']])
        _exit(0)

main()
```

So to get work with 3 pipes i imagined that i could do something like this. but it does not work.

I just change the piping() function to get an extra fork inside the child, and exchange the in/output of the channels in the new and old pipe using the dup2 method.

```py
def piping(cmd):
    print(cmd)
    r1 , w1 = pipe()
    pid = fork()
    if pid > CHILD:
        wait()
        close(w1)
        dup2(r1, STDIN)
        command(cmd[2])
    elif pid == CHILD:
        r2, w2 = pipe()
        pid2 = fork()
        if pid2 > CHILD:
            wait()
            close(w2)
            close(r1)
            dup2(w1, r2)
            command(cmd[1])
        elif pid2 == CHILD:
            close(r2)
            dup2(w2, STDOUT)
            command(cmd[0])
            _exit(0)
```

**Please help me, I really want to learn how to do this! Thank you :-)**

Comment: re: "I am imagining that I have to keep on writing the result to stdout and duplicate it in case of more pipes."  You do not want your shell reading any of the output of the children it spawns.  In the pipeline `a | b | c`, the shell just runs `b` with its stdin on the other end of the pipe from the stdout of  `a`.  If your shell is reading the output of `a` and writing it to `b`, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I am writing a | and reading | b
But I guess if I have 3 pipes: then I have to write a | write | b | and read | c, So that prevents me from calling the same function inside the child, because I am always writing a | and reading | b .

Comment: Maybe i have to make a function which can return the relevant pipe channels.

Comment: I think I figured it out now!!!! :D :D

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out!!**

I just had to make a function **child()** which would be responsible for creating new pipes and new forks. and then only write to that channel of the parent.

So i changed my **piping()** function to this.

```py
def piping(cmd):
    reading, writing = pipe()
    pid = fork()
    if pid > CHILD:
        wait()
        close(writing)
        dup2(reading, STDIN)
        command(cmd[len(cmd)-1])
    elif pid == CHILD:
        child(cmd[:-1], reading, writing)
```

And i created the **child()** function:

```py
def child(cmd, r1, w1):
    r2, w2 = pipe()
    pid2 = fork()
    if pid2 > CHILD:
        wait()
        close(w2)
        close(r1)
        dup2(r2, STDIN)
        dup2(w1, STDOUT)
        command(cmd[len(cmd)-1])
    elif pid2 == CHILD:
        if len(cmd) > 2:
            child(cmd[:-1],r2,w2)
        else:
            close(r2)
            dup2(w2, STDOUT)
            command(cmd[0])
            _exit(0)
```

and then I would be able to pass an ~infinite number of pipes to the shell and get the result ! :D